# Using max() function in r to return value and its name in vector?

Tags: r

I need to return the max value in a vector along with the index name. Day and stock price. Desired output: **Fri 34**

```
v.stock.prices <- c(23,27,23,21,34)
names(v.stock.prices) <- c('Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri')
max.price <- max(v.stock.prices)
print(max.price)
```

I get only 34 as output, how can I also return its index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
v.stock.prices[which.max(v.stock.prices)]

Fri 
 34
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `==`

```
v.stock.prices[v.stock.prices == max(v.stock.prices)]
```